# C# Top level Items

Tags: c#

I am new to C# so please excuse my ignorance on the matter.

In C++ you can define functions ( methods not in class ).

Can you do that same thing in C#, and I don't mean lambda or anonymous functions. I'm referring to the same way you can in C++.

ex.

`public void f() { }` -- not in a class.

Also this leads me to my second question, what are the only top level items you can define in C#.

Thanks :-)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

In C# methods must be enclosed in class/struct, this is basically the concept of **Encapsulation**, i.e.

> Bind the data and functions, that will operate on these data
>   together in one entity.

**Answer 2:**

You can define **struct**, **enum**, **Interface**, **Delegate** as well, as other top level items.

Comment: All methods must be in a *type* - but it doesn't have to be a class; it could be a struct.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a function that is not inside a class. C# requires all functions to be in a class (e.g. methods). You can have static functions though, which are functions you can call without having to instantiate an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is NO and you would probably find a reason for that here: 
[Why Doesn't C# Implement "Top Level" Methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`struct`, `class`, `enum`, `delegate` and `interface` - are top level items in C#.

[C# Language Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.htm) for details.